# ajax like button is updating all the product with weird values

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

I try to implemented ajax like button in my django project. I wanted like button to work in the list of company(list view) and detail view. But in list view, when I hit the like button, the like is shown 201 when it should be only 2 and when unlike it shows 200 something like that instead of 0. Also it is updating all the companies like value instead of specific company whose like button is clicked. What might be wrong in my code?

Here is the code

```
url(r'^like/company$',
    views.CompanyLikesAPIView.as_view(), name="like-company"),

class CompanyLikesAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, )

    def post(self, request, slug=None, format=None):
        company_id = request.data.get('id')
        print('company_id', company_id)
        action = request.data.get('action')
        if company_id and action:
            try:
                company = Company.objects.get(id=company_id)
                if action == "like":
                    company.likes.add(request.user)
                else:
                    company.likes.remove(request.user)
                return Response({'status': 'ok'})
            except:
                pass
        return Response({'status': 'ko'})


{% block pagecontent %}
    <div class="container">
        {% for company in companies %}
            {% with total_likes=company.likes.count users_like=company.likes.all %}
            {% if forloop.first %}<div class="row">{% endif %}
            <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card-body text-center">
                        <h3 class="card-title text-center">{{ company.name }}</h3>
                        <a href="{{ company.get_absolute_url }}" class="btn btn-link">View Detail</a>
                        <span class="count">
                            <span class="total">{{ total_likes }}</span>
                            like{{ total_likes|pluralize }}
                        </span>
                        <a href="#" data-id="{{ company.id }}" data-action="{% if request.user in users_like %}un{% endif %}like" class="company-like like-{{ company.id}} btn btn-link"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>
                        {% if request.user not in users_like %}
                            Like
                        {% else %}
                            Unlike
                        {% endif %}
                    </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:4 %}</div><br/><div class="row">{%endif %}
        {% if forloop.last %}</div>{% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock pagecontent %}


$(document).ready(function(){
      $('a.company-like').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post('{% url "products:like-company" %}',
            {
                id: $(this).data('id'),
                action: $(this).data('action')
            },
            function(data){
                if (data['status'] == 'ok')
                {
                    var previous_action = $('a.company-like').data('action');

                    // toggle data-action
                    $('a.company-like').data('action', previous_action == 'like' ? 'unlike' : 'like');
                    // toggle link text
                    $('a.company-like').text(previous_action == 'like' ? 'Unlike' : 'Like');

                    // update total likes
                    var previous_likes = parseInt($('span.count .total').text());
                    $('span.count .total').text(previous_action == 'like' ? previous_likes + 1 : previous_likes - 1);
                }
        });
    });
    });
```

The reason I am using `django-rest-framework` only for the like view is I am going to use it for developing an api later after some point of time.

Comment: post you code about `total_likes` in `views.py`

Comment: @Ykh Sorry I did not get you. Do you mean to say print the count value beneath `company.likes.add(request.user)` in the views?

Comment: `print('likes', company.likes.count())` this gives me 1 if i hit the like button of that company whose count is 0 previously which is right